# Simple War card game in python; Cards not being dealt properly

Tags: python

I'm creating a simple card game for a class I am enrolled in and am having some trouble doing some final debugging. Currently I believe the code works but cards are not being dealt into the hands of the players. I've attached the full code as well as the portions I believe are the issue.

```
import random

class Card:
  def __init__(self, rank, suit):
    self.rank = rank
    self.suit = suit
    self.value = self.calcVal()
  
  def __srt__(self):
    print(self.rank + " of " + self.suit)
  
  def stringToCard(card):
    rank, suit = card.split(" of ")
    return Card(rank,suit)

  def calcVal(self):
    if self.rank == "A":
      self.value = 14
    elif self.rank == "K":
      self.value = 13
    elif self.rank == "Q":
      self.value = 12
    elif self.rank == "J":
      self.value = 11
    else:
      self.value = int(self.rank)

  def compare(self, card2):
     if self.value > card2.value:
       return 1
     elif self.value < card2.value:
       return -1
     else:
       return 0
    
class Deck:
  def __init__(self):
    suits = ["Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"]
    ranks = ["A", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
    for suit in suits:
      for rank in ranks:
        self.cards = [Card(rank, suit)]
        print(str(self.cards))
  def shuffle(self):
    random.shuffle(self.cards)
    print("shuffled cards")

  def deal(self):
      if self.cards:
        print("cards dealt")
        return self.cards.pop()
      else:
          return None
  
class Player:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.hand = []
    self.wins = 0
  
  def collectCard(self, card):
    if isinstance(card, str):
      cardObject = Card.stringToCard(card)
      self.hand.append(cardObject)
  
  def chooseCard(self):
    if len(self.hand) > 0:
      return self.hand.pop()
    else:
      return None
  
  def playCard(self):
    return self.chooseCard()
  
class Game:
  def __init__(self, p1, p2, deck):
    self.deck = Deck()
    self.p1 = Player(p1)
    self.p2 = Player(p2)

  def beginGame(self):
    self.deck.shuffle()
    for i in range(26):
      card1 = self.deck.deal()
      card2 = self.deck.deal()
      self.p1.collectCard(card1)
      self.p2.collectCard(card2)
  
  def playRound(self):
    p1card = self.p1.playCard()
    p2card = self.p2.playCard()
    if p1card and p2card:
      if p1card.compare(p2card) == 1:
        self.p1.wins += 1
        print("Player " + self.p1.name + " wins the round! " + self.p1.name + " played " + self.p1card + " and " + self.p2.name + " played " + self.p2card + ". Player " + self.p1.name + " now has " + self.p1.wins + "wins.")
        self.p1.collectCard(p1card)
        self.p1.collectCard(p2card)
      elif p1card.compare(p2card) == -1:
        self.p2.wins += 1
        print("Player " + self.p2.name + " wins the round! " + self.p2.name + " played " + self.p2card + " and " + self.p1.name + " played " + self.p1card + ". Player " + self.p2.name + " now has " + self.p2.wins + "wins.")
        self.p2.collectCard(p1card)
        self.p2.collectCard(p2card)
      else:
        self.war(p1card, p2card)
    else:
      print("A player has run out of cards!")
  
  def war(self, card1, card2):
    print("War!")
    p1warcards = [self.p1.chooseCard() for x in range(3)]
    p2warcards = [self.p2.chooseCard() for x in range(3)]
    warcards = []
    warcards.append(p1warcards)
    warcards.append(p2warcards)
    if len(p1warcards) < 3 or len(p2warcards) < 3:
      print("Someone does't have enough cards for War!")
      return
    
    p1warcard = self.p1.playCard()
    p2warcard = self.p2.playCard()
    if p1warcard and p2warcard:
      if p1warcard.compare(p2warcard) == 1:
        self.p1.wins+=1
        print("Player " + self.p1.name + " wins the round! " + self.p1.name + " played " + self.p1card + " and " + self.p2.name + " played " + self.p2card + ". Player " + self.p1.name + " now has " + self.p1.wins + "wins.")
        self.p1.collectCard(p1warcard)
        self.p1.collectCard(p2warcard)
        self.p1.collectCard(warcards)
      if p1warcard.compare(p2warcard) == -1:
        self.p2.wins+=1
        print("Player " + self.p1.name + " wins the round! " + self.p1.name + " played " + self.p1card + " and " + self.p2.name + " played " + self.p2card + ". Player " + self.p1.name + " now has " + self.p1.wins + "wins.")
        self.p2.collectCard(p1warcard)
        self.p2.collectCard(p2warcard)
        self.p2.collectCard(warcards)
      else:
        return self.war(p1warcard, p2warcard)
    else:
      if p1warcard:
        self.p1.collectCard(warcards)
      else:
        self.p2.collect(warcards)

player1 = input("Welcome to my War game! Please begin by entering the name of player one.\n")
player2 = input("Now please enter the name of player 2.\n")
p2 = Player(player2)
p1 = Player(player1)
newDeck = Deck()
newgame = Game(player1, player2, newDeck)
newgame.beginGame()
x = 0
while x < 5:
  x += 1
  newgame.playRound()
```

Believed issues

```
class Game:
  def __init__(self, p1, p2, deck):
    self.deck = Deck()
    self.p1 = Player(p1)
    self.p2 = Player(p2)

  def beginGame(self):
    self.deck.shuffle()
    for i in range(26):
      card1 = self.deck.deal()
      card2 = self.deck.deal()
      self.p1.collectCard(card1)
      self.p2.collectCard(card2)
```

Have been using print statements inside of each function to identify the problem. I've narrowed it down to the cards being created but not being dealt into the hands of the players before the game begins.

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Just to amplify the python debugger, you can add a `from pdb import set_trace; set_trace()` and that'll plop you down into the spot where you want to check variables, the stack, whatever... If you can, I suggest you `python 3-m pip install --user ipdb` which is much better to use than vanilla `pdb`.

Comment: Suggest you add a function to your Player class to print the contents of player's hand.  You can the utilize this function, to see what cards are in each user's hand at the beginning of the game as well as after each round.  Additionally, during debug, shorten the number of cards initially dealt to maybe 3 or 4 to begin.

Comment: _Have been using print statements inside of each function to identify the problem_ It would help if you showed that output, along with an explanation of **why** it is wrong, and what you **expected** to see instead.

Answer (score 1):

The very first thing is that a deck of cards only has 52 cards, the "A" and the "1" are the same rank.  These kinds of one-off errors are endemic to programming and you should be much more careful.

So, the second issue I see is on line 42:
`self.cards = [Card(rank, suit)]`.
This is resetting the value of self.cards, each time.  I'd re-write this section using either a list comprehension or a collector list:

```py
    self.cards = [Card(rank, suit) for suit in suits for rank in ranks]
    print(str(self.cards))
```

List comprehensions are a powerful and set notation-like python syntax that you should [learn](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Next, your magic Card,**srt**(self) is not working.  [The difference between `__str__` and `__repr__` is not always clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/what-is-the-difference-between-str-and-repr), but to make your code work, I rewrote is as a `__repr__`:

```py
  def __repr__(self):
    return ' '.join([self.rank,"of",self.suit])
```

Now, in this function:

```
     60   def collectCard(self, card):
---> 61     if isinstance(card, str):
     62       cardObject = Card.stringToCard(card)
     63       self.hand.append(cardObject)
```

??? What is this? This is checking to see if the card is a string, the type of the card here is a card.  I'm uncertain why you've done this at all.  By modifying this function to *simply* add the card to the hand:

```py
  def collectCard(self, card):
    if isinstance(card, str):
      cardObject = Card.stringToCard(card)
      self.hand.append(cardObject)
    elif isinstance(card, Card):
      self.hand.append(card)
```

**Whew** this is a lot of bugs...

Next, your `__init__` for `self.value = self.calcVal()` undoes the setting of `self.value` because `self.calcVal` doesn't have a return statement, overwriting the `self.value` to be `None`.  So, I changed the `calcVal` to do that:

```py
  def calcVal(self):
    if self.rank == "A":
      self.value = 14
    elif self.rank == "K":
      self.value = 13
    elif self.rank == "Q":
      self.value = 12
    elif self.rank == "J":
      self.value = 11
    else:
      self.value = int(self.rank)
    return self.value
```

I'm going to stop here.  I think that I'm doing your homework at this point.  Why don't you take these points and see if you can get it to work from here.

Happy Debugging.